# Loading server side pages with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic

please i load a server side page using ajax on my jquery mobile page with this code

```
 <script language="javascript">
$('#try').bind('pageshow', function (){


    var url = window.location.search.substring(1);

    $('#try').load('real_news.asp?'+ url);
});
</script>
```

But the problem is when i load the page into the div, it doesn't load but reads out the code in the div like this:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>

<!--#include file="../Connections/tv.asp" -->
<%
Dim rs_read__MMColParam
rs_read__MMColParam = "1"
If (Request.QueryString("news_id")  <> "") Then 
  rs_read__MMColParam = Request.QueryString("news_id") 
End If
%>
<%
Dim rs_read
Dim rs_read_cmd
Dim rs_read_numRows

Set rs_read_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rs_read_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_tv_STRING
rs_read_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM news_update WHERE news_id = ?" 
rs_read_cmd.Prepared = true
rs_read_cmd.Parameters.Append rs_read_cmd.CreateParameter("param1", 5, 1, -1, rs_read__MMColParam) ' adDouble

Set rs_read = rs_read_cmd.Execute
rs_read_numRows = 0
%>
```

Comment: *sidenote:* please replace `<script language="javascript">` with `<script type="text/javascript">` (HTML 4.01) or `<script>` (HTML 5)

Comment: i've done that and still the same error

Comment: *sidenote* will not solve your problem. Just want to point out that your code is out-dated.

Comment: Does your server support ASP ?

Comment: yes, when i try on ripple emulator it works out fine cos it's running on IIS but on the android emulator it doesn't work

Comment: The client shouldn't matter, ASP runs on the server.

Comment: yeah my server supports ASP.  it's able to load some asp pages into some divs but i don't know why its not working now with a new div on a new page

Comment: If the code is responded directly to your HTTP request, it probably means the ASP is treated as text file. Try to execute a small script in the server

Comment: yes this is what i'm trying to say, the code is executed as a text file. but the funny thing is it's working fine on my web browsers and and on chrome ripple emulators, but executes as a text file on android phones and emulators

Comment: You could make the asp file create an actual static file and than open that one

Answer (score 0):

Sound like the asp page is not interpreted. Are you running the code on IIS server?
Also check if the asp extension is resisted on IIS. By default ASP is not installed on IIS 7.5.
Check this [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis) for more info or how to enable ASP (classic) on IIS7.5